# How to evaluate the product:

Tags: infinite-product

How to evaluate the product:

$$\prod _{n=2}^\infty\left(1+\dfrac{1}{n^2}+\dfrac{1}{n^4}+\dfrac{1}{n^6}+\dfrac{1}{n^8}+\ldots\right)$$

$$\left(1+\dfrac{1}{n^2}+\dfrac{1}{n^4}+\dfrac{1}{n^6}+\dfrac{1}{n^8}+\ldots\right)=\dfrac{1}{1-\dfrac{1}{n^2}}$$

How to proceed now?

Comment: *Hint:* $\dfrac{1}{1-\dfrac{1}{n^2}} = \dfrac{n^2}{(n-1)(n+1)}$ and see if the product has some mass cancellation.

Comment: @r9m: very nice. why don't you submit this as an answer.

Comment: thank you very much it was excellent @r9m

Answer (score 4):

Proceeding $\scr{r9m's} $ suggestion:
$$\require{cancel}\frac1{1-1/n^2}=\frac{n\cdot n}{(n-1)(n+1)}\\\prod_{n=2}^{\infty}\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac1{n^{2k}}=\prod_{n=2}^{\infty}\frac{n\cdot n}{(n-1)(n+1)}\\=\lim_{n\to\infty}\underbrace{\frac21\cdot\frac {\cancel{\color{blue}{2}}}{\cancel{\color{red}{3}}}}_{t_1}\cdot\underbrace{\frac{\cancel{\color{red}{3}}}{\cancel{\color{blue}{2}}}\cdot\frac {\cancel{\color{fuchsia}{3}}}{\cancel{\color{green}{4}}}}_{t_2}\cdot\underbrace{\frac{\cancel{\color{green}{4}}}{\cancel{\color{fuchsia}{3}}}\cdots}_{t_3}\cdots\underbrace{\frac {\cancel{\color{maroon}{n}}}{\cancel{\color{orange}{n-1}}}\frac n{n+1}}_{t_n} =\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{2n}{n+1}=2$$

Comment: why answer in the same lines as done by someone else?i have finished this anyway thanks

Comment: @learningmaths since sometimes there's only one short way out, neglecting other tedious and useless long methods

Comment: @Learnmore It's better to have the answer written as an answer, not just a comment. BTW, if this is a satisfactory answer, you should mark it as accepted.